# Need to put Json link that contains img url in < img ng-src

Tags: javascript, html, json, firebase

I am currently using `Firebase` and `Ionic` to build a mobile app and I have to use the json link of firebase that contains an image url in my html img ng-src.

Here is the [Json link](https://wellesleytesting.firebaseio.com/userProfile/userimg.json) that contains an url of an image.

I want to put this link into img and get the url that is contained in this json link (`"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg"`)  and display the image, but I am not sure how to do this?

Here is what I have in html so far.

```
<img src="'https://wellesleytesting.firebaseio.com/userProfile/userimg.json'" />
```

Any help would be really appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: <img ng-src="'https://wellesleytesting.firebaseio.com/userProfile/userimg.json '"/>
 I meant this is what I have so far

Comment: That JSON link now leads to `null`, which is one of the reasons you should include the JSON in the question itself (as text, no screenshot) instead of linking to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make an `http` request on your json link which will send you the image link as a response.

```
$http.get("https://wellesleytesting.firebaseio.com/userProfile/userimg.json")
.then(function(response) {
    $scope.imgSrc = response.data;
    $scope.imgSrc = JSON.parse($scope.imgSrc)        
});
```

Once you have your response, you have to parse it like :

```
$scope.imgSrc = JSON.parse($scope.imgSrc)
```

Finally bind it to your html with `ng-src` attribute :

```
<img ng-src="{{imgSrc}}"/>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3098/)

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for your response! I see. So is there no way to do it directly in Html? Because I have ng-repeat that will go through a list of images, so if I need to do http request, I would need to pass a function to ng-src, <img ng-src="{{getImg(event.eventImgJsonUrl)}}">.

Comment: Hmm not sure what you mean, but if you want to show a list of images, you can first get all the images sources like in my answer. Push it into a list like `$scope.listImages.push(imgSrc)` and display it with `"ng-repeat = img in listImages"` something like that i guess

Comment: here is what I mean I have           
<div ng-repeat=" event in events = (allEvents | filter: searchParam )">
                                <h2>{{event.displayName}}</h2>
                                    <b>Description:</b> {{event.description}}
                                <!--                                <img ng-src="https://wellesleytesting.firebaseio.com/+{{event.userID}}+userProfile/userimg.json" />-->


</div>

Comment: so I was asking that I cant get the image directly html, I should pass in a function to get each individually.                          <img ng-src="{{getProfile(event.userID)}}"> Apologize for confusion and thank you so much for your help!!!!

Comment: As I said you can push all your images source into a list, and `repeat` with `ng-src={{img}}` (`ng-repeat = img in listImages `), you don't need extra functions, maybe edit your question with more details

Comment: http://prnt.sc/axejk5
Here is a link to my data structure. Basically, I am using ng-repeat to loop through the event branch for each event already, and for each event, I want to be able to go reference user branch to get user's profile picture. Does that make sense? So I need to do http request for each event, but when I did the function method I mentioned, I got an error.  [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []

Comment: It does make sense but I can't help with a simple image, edit your question with the correct `events` and `users` variable. A sample will be nice. You can use https://jsfiddle.net/ as well

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < allEvents.length; i++) {
                var eventForThis = allEvents[i];
                    eventForThis.profileImg = whateverimgIwant;
} 
In the end, I got it to work like this. going through a for loop and assign the image to each variable :) Thanks for your help thou!